# Reshape pandas dataframe for multiple columns

Tags: pandas

I am trying to convert the following pandas df

```
Error   Fore    time    loc qty           con   FA
2960    32863   2086    CFA Ahmedabad   29903   1   90
2960    32863   2087    CFA Ahmedabad   29903   1   90
8090    71453   2086    CFA Bangalore   79543   2   90
8090    71453   2087    CFA Bangalore   79543   2   90
```

to

```
loc              var      2086    2087
CFA Ahmedabad   qty    29903    29903
CFA Ahmedabad   Fore    32863     32863
CFA Ahmedabad   Error   2960      2960
CFA Ahmedabad   con      1       1
CFA Ahmedabad   FA       90      90
```

I have tried using melt/stack but nothing seems worked

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='loc', value_vars=var, value_name='time')
```

this code is not working to get columns as time, any idea will be much appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you can use [`melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) + [`pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
m=df.melt(['time','loc']).pivot_table(index=['loc','variable'],columns='time')
print(m)
```

---

```
time                     2086   2087
loc           variable              
CFA Ahmedabad Error      2960   2960
              FA           90     90
              Fore      32863  32863
              con           1      1
              qty       29903  29903
CFA Bangalore Error      8090   8090
              FA           90     90
              Fore      71453  71453
              con           2      2
              qty       79543  79543
```